# Ubuntu 14.04 does not detect windows 8.1 in legacy mode

Tags: uefi

I want to install ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows 8.1 on lenovo in legacy mode. I am using rufus but when I'm installing ubuntu then it says" No other operating system detected" and the option is to either erase all data or something else. i do not want my windows gone. Please help me with this.

Comment: Do you know if Windows is set up using MBR or GPT? This is important because if your installer is MBR and Windows is using GPT, it won't see it.

Comment: No I dont know about it at all.

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). (You can do this from the Ubuntu installer in its "try before installing" mode.) This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.